# Waiting for a change in boolean state and then starting an activity?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a simple implementation of a CountDownTimer that counts to 0. When it reaches 0, it changes the state of a boolean from false to true.

I want to start an activity when the boolean result turns true but I'm not quite sure how to implement it. (I have researched threading and I'm confused whether to use CountDownLatch or Mutexes)

What is the best way of implementing something like this which does not strain the CPU while also allowing the activity to function?

Comment: why not just call startActivity() right before or after you change the boolean?

Comment: @FoamyGuy wow this idea completely whizzed past my head.... sorry for the inconvenience everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just start the activity in your onFinish() method

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         Log.e("myapp","tick");
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
         CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
     }
  }.start();
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of doing this, thank you & FoamyGuy. (will accept answer when possible)